# How to remove or hide MarkerView in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I did a bar chart with [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). I did a custom marker view class to view the values of the bar.
I would remove or hide the view after some seconds. It should work as a toast. But I cannot do it.
This is a problem first of all because after I touched the chart for the first time, it becomes visible and it disappears only if i find the right tapped condition.

There is someone who knows how solve this problem?

In my code I have:

```
mChart.invalidate();
mv = new CustomMarkerView(getContext(), R.layout.alert_chart, position, jsonResponse);
mChart.setMarker(mv);
```

And my CustomMarkerView is

```
public class CustomMarkerViewextends MarkerView {

public TextView correct;
public TextView wrong ;
public int position;
public JSONArray jsonArray;

public CustomMarkerView(Context context, int layoutResource, int pos, JSONArray json) {
    super(context, layoutResource);

    correct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.correct);
    wrong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wrong);

    position = pos;
    jsonArray = json;

}

@Override
public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {
    switch (position){
        case 1:
            try {
                correct.setText(getContext().getString(R.string.correct_alert) + "   " + jsonArray.getJSONObject((int)(e.getX())).getString("TP"));
                wrong.setText(getContext().getString(R.string.wrong_alert) + "   " + jsonArray.getJSONObject((int)(e.getX())).getString("FP"));        
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            break;
        case 2:
            try {
                correct.setText(getContext().getString(R.string.tpr_alert) + "   " + Math.round(Double.parseDouble(jsonArray.getJSONObject((int)(e.getX())).getString("TPR"))*100.0)/100.0);
                wrong.setText(getContext().getString(R.string.msr_alert) + "   " + Math.round(Double.parseDouble(jsonArray.getJSONObject((int)(e.getX())).getString("MSR"))*100.0)/100.0);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            break;
        case 3:
            try {
                correct.setText(getContext().getString(R.string.nmean_alert) + "   " +Math.round(Double.parseDouble(jsonArray.getJSONObject((int)(e.getX())).getString("n_mean"))*100.0)/100.0);
                wrong.setText(getContext().getString(R.string.nmax_alert) + "   " +Math.round(Double.parseDouble(jsonArray.getJSONObject((int)(e.getX())).getString("n_max"))*100.0)/100.0);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            break;
    }

    // this will perform necessary layouting
    super.refreshContent(e, highlight);

}

private MPPointF mOffset;

@Override
public MPPointF getOffset() {

    if(mOffset == null) {
        // center the marker horizontally and vertically
        mOffset = new MPPointF(-(getWidth()/2), -getHeight());
    }

    return mOffset;
}
```

}

Comment: Did u find the answer to this problem ?

Answer (score 8):

I know, it's a bit late, but:

```
mChart.highlightValue(null);
```

Worked for me

Comment: Is there some way to remove markers from an individual data set, while another data set can still have them?

Comment: @mtsahakis, don't know exactly if it's possible or not by that library, but what you can do is to keep track of highlighted elements and when you need to remove highlight from specific data set - just call mChart.highlightValue(null); and then rehighlight all needed values.

Comment: @mtsahakis try this dataSet.setDrawHighlightIndicators(false)

Comment: @mtsahakis dataSet.setHighlightEnabled(false) to disable interaction on a specific data set instead of all chart

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer. It works, sort of. Now if I touch the chart and move my finger to trigger the ACTION_MOVE event, and then untouch, the markview disappear. But when I tap on the chart, It will only trigger MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, but this time, the markview is still shown? How to fix this. Thanks. @Vadim

Answer (score 3):

Set an onTouchListener to your chart and in the MotionEvent ACTION_UP set the highlight value to null. Code :

```
chart.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    chart.highlightValue(null);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Also, if you need to hide this the marker, for instance, on the scroll changes, it's better to check marker visibility using `chart.valuesToHighlight()`

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer. It works, sort of. Now if I touch the chart and move my finger to trigger the ACTION_MOVE event, and then untouch, the markview disappear. But when I tap on the chart, It will only trigger MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, but this time, the markview is still shown? How to fix this. Thanks. @Nick Asher